# Coefficients Matrix in the discretization of the ground water equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand a certain part in this article [FINITE VOLUME METHOD OF MODELLING TRANSIENT GROUNDWATER FLOW](http://thescipub.com/abstract/10.3844/jmssp.2014.92.110).

The discretized flow equation is given as [image: eq 29]`
For a cell centered with 4 neighbors this  is given as:

After a few simplfication and renaming of terms the equation becomes:

[image]

where the time derivative is expressed in terms of `k+1`
and `k`, implicit Euler method. The authors than express this equation as 38. And the show the coefficients matrix for a 3 by 3 grid:

```
7 | 8 | 9
- + - + -
4 | 5 | 6
- + - + -
1 | 2 | 3
```

[image]

I get why the 5th cell has `-(4 + M)` if I think about the incoming and outgoing flux terms (it has 4 neighboring cells). But I don't understand how the authors calculate the other coefficients for that matrix.

#### update - boundary conditions

The following boundary conditions are defined:

[image]

Comment: Do you have Neumann boundary conditions by occasion? It looks like $h_{i\pm 1,j} = h_{i,j}$ conditions were used to elimiate non-existent $h_{i\pm 1,j}$ (same for y direction)

Comment: @uranix, thanks for looking at it. I updated the question, adding the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $i = 1, j = 1$ you have the equation
$$
h^{k+1}_{i+1, j}
+h^{k+1}_{i-1, j}
+h^{k+1}_{i, j+1}
+h^{k+1}_{i, j-1}
-(4+M)h^{k+1}_{i,j} = M h^{k}_{i,j}
$$
as
$$
h^{k+1}_{2, 1}
+h^{k+1}_{0, 1}
+h^{k+1}_{1, 2}
+h^{k+1}_{1, 0}
-(4+M)h^{k+1}_{1,1} = M h^{k}_{1,1}.
$$
Substituting approximated Neumann condition at $x = 0$ $h^{k+1}_{0,1} = h^{k+1}_{1,1}$ and $h^{k+1}_{1,0} = h^{k+1}_{1,1}$ at $y = 0$ we have
$$
h^{k+1}_{2, 1}
+h^{k+1}_{1, 1}
+h^{k+1}_{1, 2}
+h^{k+1}_{1, 1}
-(4+M)h^{k+1}_{1,1} 
\equiv
h^{k+1}_{2, 1}
+h^{k+1}_{1, 2}
-(2+M)h^{k+1}_{1,1} 
= M h^{k}_{1,1}.
$$

At $i = 3, j = 3$ the equation is
$$
h^{k+1}_{4, 3}
+h^{k+1}_{2, 3}
+h^{k+1}_{3, 4}
+h^{k+1}_{3, 2}
-(4+M)h^{k+1}_{3,3} = M h^{k}_{3,3}.
$$
Substituting $h^{k+1}_{4,3}$ from the Dirichlet boundary condition
$$
\frac{h^{k+1}_{4,3} + h^{k+1}_{3,3}}{2} = 12\\
h^{k+1}_{4,3} = 24 - h^{k+1}_{3,3}
$$
and similarly $h^{k+1}_{3,4} = 24 - h^{k+1}_{3,3}$ gives
$$
(24 - h^{k+1}_{3,3})
+h^{k+1}_{2, 3}
+(24 - h^{k+1}_{3,3})
+h^{k+1}_{3, 2}
-(4+M)h^{k+1}_{3,3} 
\equiv \\ \equiv
48 +h^{k+1}_{2, 3} +h^{k+1}_{3, 2}
-(6+M)h^{k+1}_{3,3} 
= M h^{k}_{3,3}\\
h^{k+1}_{2, 3} +h^{k+1}_{3, 2}
-(6+M)h^{k+1}_{3,3} 
= M h^{k}_{3,3} - 48\\
$$

The same idea works for every other boundary point.

Comment: can you explain how you did the expansion where you ended up with -(6+M). Is this some trivial algebraic trick I don't know ?

Comment: @Oz123 No, that's just a typo. I've corrected the equation

Comment: That is clearer now. Thank you for that